# What's wrong with my reverse lookup zone?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I am in the process of building a small network with several servers. I am using Server 2008 R2 and have one server (adc01.m6.local  = 10.18.1.1) running as the domain controller and DNS server.

The issue is that reverse lookups do not seem to be working.

Forward zone:

```
;
;  Zone:    m6.local
;  Server:  adc01.m6.local
;  Time:    Wed Jan 19 23:03:37 2011 UTC
;
@ [Aging:3594426] 600 A 10.18.1.1
         3600 NS    adc01.m6.local.
         3600 SOA   adc01.m6.local. hostmaster.m6.local. 23 900 600 86400 3600
_msdcs 3600 NS  adc01.m6.local.
_gc._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites [Aging:3594426] 600 SRV 0 100 3268 adc01.m6.local.
adc01 3600 A    10.18.1.1
DomainDnsZones [Aging:3594426] 600 A    10.18.1.1
ForestDnsZones [Aging:3594426] 600 A    10.18.1.1
```

I added a new reverse zone like this:

```
;
;  Zone:    1.18.10.in-addr.arpa
;  Server:  adc01.m6.local
;  Time:    Wed Jan 19 23:05:30 2011 UTC
;
@ 3600 NS   adc01.m6.local.
         3600 SOA   adc01.m6.local. hostmaster.m6.local. 1 900 600 86400 3600
```

This is the error:

```
c:\nslookup 10.18.1.1
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1

*** UnKnown can't find 10.18.1.1: Non-existent domain
```

What did I do wrong?

Rick

Comment: Are there PTR records there that you arn't showing or do you have no PTR records in the Reverse zone?

Comment: Is there a command to display them? I wanted to upload some screenshots but I don't have the rep yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following steps to create the reverse lookup zone:

Open DNS Manager, right-click Reverse Lookup Zones, choose New Zone, follow the wizard and when "Reverse Lookup Zone Name" page appear, choose "Reverse lookup zone name" option and type:

( This is my example only )
192 - 254.111.199.66.in - addr.arpa

Finish the wizard and test. For your information:

Adding a Reverse Lookup Zone
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961414.aspx

Please visit below mentioned url for more help

http://cohesivelogic.com/2009/11/how-to-create-ptr-entries-for-a-classless-reverse-dns-zone-on-windows-2008/

Thanks.